# Docker compose ignoring ipv4_address in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
  box1:
    hostname: box1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: box.Dockerfile
    networks:
      testing: 
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.10
    command: |
      /bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'
  box2:
    hostname: box2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: box.Dockerfile
    networks:
      testing: 
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.20
    command: |
      /bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'
  box3:
    hostname: box3
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: box.Dockerfile
    networks:
      testing: 
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.30
    command: |
      /bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'
networks:
  testing:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.1.0/24
          gateway: 172.28.1.1/
          aux_addresses: 
            box1: 172.28.1.10
            box2: 172.28.1.20
            box3: 172.28.1.30
```

I tried every combination and hint on internet, but no matter what I try, docker compose is assigning another IP addresses to containers then those I am using in specification.

When I try `docker exec box_1 /bin/sh -c 'ifconfig'` or `dig` for dns of another container, I am getting random IP addresses instead of those that are set for every container.

I am running docker desktop for mac 3.3.1 (63152)

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to meaningfully use a macvlan network using docker for mac (because Docker is running inside a Linux vm whose interfaces don't connect to anything that will be useful to you when running in macvlan mode).

Comment: This was just last desperate attempt. Is there any other driver that would do this thing?

Comment: What exactly is your goal?

Comment: To assign fixed IP address to every docker container started in this way so I can use host->IP in reliable way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem when using `docker compose up` on macOS. Using `docker-compose up` (note the `-` sign) resolved it.

Comment: How is this a thing?!?!?! I tried literally everything else I could find and this is what fixed it for me on Windows 10

Comment: This has been fixed in their code in the meantime: https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1582

Comment: BTW, I am still seeing this issue on my Mac with freshly updated Docker Desktop 3.5.1 (engine: 20.10.7, compose 1.29.2)

Comment: dockers great till you spend a week looking into an issue and find its a hyphen. I guess docker team wants to convert the old syntax "docker-compose" to "docker compose". The later is V2 syntax and seems not everything is compatible in the yaml. This post saved my but. Everything seemed to be working fine with 2 services and when I tried to add more I kept running into strange issues with IP lookups. Bout to seriously start looking at podman as a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed that with macOS and the latest 3.3.3 release of Docker Desktop, the `docker-compose` version is still 1.0-alpha and exhibits this behavior of assigned an IP address and the beginning of the network range, starting with `.2`

As Yannick correctly mentioned, using the external `docker-compose` command does assign the correct `ipv4_address`. Note: didn't comment on Yannick's answer as I don't the reputation yet (but I did upvote it :)).

When using `docker-compose` version `1.29.1`, this worked correctly. In my case where I'm focused on ECS container agents, the result of `docker network inspect` returns the following:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "ggv2_dev_docker_greengrass_tes",
        "Id": "ede0aff6f7680aba4eb4a905904b1613d0d653f58cce856ff44e2b817a1f0218",
        "Created": "2021-05-14T16:15:25.974565062Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "169.254.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "9ab191ea02ef7b567e9883ec3a74e89eae455e843924bdd27f5a6e219d11dca2": {
                "Name": "aws-iot-greengrass-dev",
                "EndpointID": "5238d4dadeaeaa57af306859a2f3ff8ec619c9f7ebe43b632ba1caa4c2b4d2b1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:a9:fe:aa:02",
                "IPv4Address": "169.254.170.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "greengrass_tes",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "ggv2_dev_docker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.1"
        }
    }
]
```

where the target `169.254.170.2` is being properly assigned.